# Javascript lookup table

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, lookup

I have an object which holds my data.

```
 DataSoccer: [{ 0: '0.00', 1: '10.4', 2:'100.5', 3:'15.3', 4:'11.2', 5:'15.9'}]
```

when the key values are whole this is simple.

DataSoccer[0][1] //returns 10.4

The problem is the indexes are now not whole

```
  DataSoccer: [{ 0: '0.00', 1.30: '10.4', 2.40:'100.5', 3.40:'15.3', 4.5:'11.2', 5:'15.9'}]
```

so I get a user input, say 2.30 and that should return 10.4 (the second index)

At the moment I have an if statement

```
if (value == 0 {
return 0.00
}
else if (value <= 1.30) {
   return 10.4
}

else if (value > 1.30 value < 2.40) {
   return 100.5
}
```

As you can imagine this lookup functionality using an if-else can get pretty cumbersome and was wondering if there was a better way?

Comment: You've got an array with only 1 element (an object with all of those properties and values). Why not use an array to hold them?

Comment: ok, an array would be fine, but it does not solve the look issue?

Comment: The conversion to string may be dropping zeros. `DataSoccer[0]["1.3"]`.

Comment: is input 2.3 --> 10.4 a typo? or do you really want something like the "closest" neighbour?

Comment: why should 2.3 return 10.4 and not 100.5?

Comment: @LeBlaireau your if-else logic suggest that 2.4 should return 100.5 not 10.4

Comment: @LeBlaireau: As everyone here is confused about what you really want to achieve, maybe you should clarify your question.

Comment: @lipp yes that is correct

Comment: @ gurvinder372 updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
var DataSoccer =  [{ 0: '0.00', 1.30: '10.4', 2.40:'100.5', 3.40:'15.3', 4.5:'11.2', 5:'15.9'}];

//sort all the keys in DataSoccer[0]
var sortedKeys = Object.keys(DataSoccer[0]).sort(function(a,b){ return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b) }); 

//get value lesser than 2.3 which is 1.3
var smallerKey = sortedKeys.filter(function(val){ return val < 2.3}).pop(); 

//get next value which is 2.4 after 1.3
var actualKey = sortedKeys[sortedKeys.indexOf(smallerKey) + 1]; 

//alerting the value at 2.4
alert("value is " + DataSoccer[0][actualKey] ); //access value ar 2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for getting a value with one iteration.

```js
function getValue(p) {
    return object[Object.keys(object).reduce(function (r, k) {
        return k <= r || k > p ? r: k;
    }, undefined)];
}

var object = { 0: '0.00', 1.30: '10.4', 2.40: '100.5', 3.40: '15.3', 4.5: '11.2', 5: '15.9' };

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getValue(2.3), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

This is an annotation to object literals with number as key.

The properties of objects are strings but in this case they are numbers and then converted to strings.

```js
var DataSoccer = [{ 0: '0.00', 1.30: '10.4', 2.40:'100.5', 3.40:'15.3', 4.5:'11.2', 5:'15.9'}];
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(DataSoccer, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write(DataSoccer[0]['2.4']);
```

Comment: the user wants to access  2.30  (which is not part of the array)